# Compilation error "type mismatch" at line Cookie cookie[]= req.getCookies();

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am currently using the latest version of eclipse and tomcat server(v8.5)

type mismatch error is being generated in SqServlets.java file in "Cookie cookie[]= req.getCookies();" line of my code.

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Cookie;

public class SqServlets extends HttpServlet {
    
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
        
        Cookie cookie[]= req.getCookies();
        
        // ...      
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add error to your post

Comment: does `i` and `j` have some values in it or not in your `Addservlet` class ,try to check .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the error is in the import:

```
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.parser.Cookie;
```

From the documentation of HttpServletRequest we have that the method `getCookies` returns a `javax.servlet.http.Cookie` that is not compatible with your declaration.

So fix the import with:

`import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;`

And then use the relative API to find and get the value of your cookie.

Comment: for(Cookie c : Cookie) {
   
   if(c.getName().equals("k")) {
    k=Integer.parseInt(c.getValue());
   }
  }

Comment: I have used the above code to get a cookie but it gives me an error.

Comment: Type Exception Report

Message null

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 servlets.Addservlet.doGet(Addservlet.java:15)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)